# question mark in IN statement

Tags: sql

This is my query:

```
select top 6 Nr,'<a href=[url]?id=' + convert(varchar,Nr) + '&ch=TRA&channel=TRA>' + isnull(menutitle,title) + '</a>'    as title
             from vwActive
             where NR IN  (select nr from dbo.fn_RecurseChildren('4',0)) 
             and parent not in (6985,54092,29,28,98086,97126) 
  and Nr not in (?)

                          and isnull(ShowFrom,AddDate) >=(getdate()-14)
             and contentType<>7 
             and hiddenchild=0
 and (Body NOT LIKE '' AND Body NOT LIKE '<P>&nbsp;</P>' 
                  or Description NOT LIKE '' AND Description NOT LIKE '<P>&nbsp;</P>'
             ) 

and nr not in(
               select replace(ctspecificvar1,char(91)+'item'+char(93)+'=','') link
               from vwactive
               where hiddenchild=0  and parent=6985
               and contenttype=7
               and isnumeric(replace(ctspecificvar1,char(91)+'item'+char(93)+'=',''))=1
             )

 and nr not in (
                 select case when isnumeric(replace(ctspecificvar1, '[item]=', '')) = 1 then convert(int,replace(isnull(ctspecificvar1, 0), '[item]=', '')) else 0 end link
                 from vwActive
                 where contenttype=7 and hiddenchild=0 and parent=6985 
             )
```

but I get an error on this statement:

```
and Nr not in (?)
```

But if I omit that statement then the query works.

But how to let the query work with the statement:

and Nr not in (?)

Thank you

Comment: What are you expecting `IN(?)` to do for you?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Why do you have that line in your query?

Comment: And what flavour of SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark is supposed to be filled with parameters, i.e. replaced with a list of numbers that are supposed to be excluded by the query.

So if you don't care, just delete that line (or comment it out using '--').

If you care, put Nr values in there that you want to exclude.

Comment: Question marks are parameter markers in dynamic SQL. I.e prepare the statement, provide input parameters, and execute the statement.